# Как в go сделать переменную с двумя типами и функцию вовращающую два типа

Tags: golang

Как сделать так чтобы в переменной left можно было хранить как NumberNode так и BinaryOperationNode, и чтобы функция могла вовращать оба эти типа?

Код:

```
func (p *Parser) Term() BinaryOperationNode {
    left := p.Factor() // Factor возвращает NumberNode

    for p.CurrentToken.Type_ == token.Number {
        operation := p.CurrentToken
        right := p.Factor()
        left := node.BinaryOperationNode{LeftOperand: left.Value, RightOperand: right.Value, Operation: operation.Value}

    }

    return left
}
```

Comment: Заведите для них общий интерфейс и возвращайте его.

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Чтобы не возвращать число, возвращайте бинарную операцию, которая складывает это число с нулем.

Comment: Покажите определение типа `BinaryOperationNode`.

Comment: type BinaryOperationNode struct {
 LeftOperand  string
 RightOperand string
 Operation    string

 Result int
}

Comment: func (bop *BinaryOperationNode) Eval() {
 lftop, _ := strconv.Atoi(bop.LeftOperand)
 rghtop, _ := strconv.Atoi(bop.RightOperand)

 switch bop.Operation {
 case "+":
  bop.Result = lftop + rghtop
 case "-":
  bop.Result = lftop - rghtop
 case "*":
  bop.Result = lftop * rghtop
 case "/":
  bop.Result = lftop / rghtop
 }
}

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Делаю небольшой интерпретатор, сейчас делаю калькулятор

Comment: Могли бы вы показать как мне сделать общий интерфейс и переменную left?

Comment: Во всех Nodes есть функция Eval() она нечего не возвращает

Comment: Сделайте чтобы `Eval` возвращал значение и заведите `type Evaler interface { Eval() float64 }`.

Comment: type Nodes interface { Eval() }; var left Nodes = p.NumberNode{"3", 0} // Ошибка

Comment: А можно обойтись без этого?

Comment: Без этого обойтись трудно. Вы собираетесь что-то сделать с возвращаемым значением. Что с ним можно сделать? Какую-то операцию общую для обоих типов. Что это за операция? Та что описана в общем интерфейсе.